# Using nivoslider in a pre defined div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to include `NivoSlider` into a `div` with id `imageslider` into my page. I have tried following the tutorial on their [website](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/), but with no effect for four days now. Please check it out :

---

*index.php*

```
<!-- In the head section I have included these --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Somewhere in the body section -->
<div id="imageslider">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
         <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="abc.jpeg" alt="" height="360" width="700"/>
            <img src="uvw.jpeg" alt="" height="360" width="700"/>
            <img src="pqr.jpeg" alt="" height="360" width="700"/>
            <img src="xyz.jpeg" alt="" height="360" width="700"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Also at the end of the body tag-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

---

*In my style sheet, style.css*

```
#imageslider {
float: right;
width: 700px;
background-color: blue;
height: 360px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 15px; 
}

/*Rest styles are copied from the website itself*/
.nivoSlider {
position:relative;
background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.nivoSlider img {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}

.nivoSlider a {
border:0;
display:block;
}
```

---

When I open or refresh the page, no image appears in the `imageslider` div. Please help me out here !!

Comment: check out your images are placed in correct path

Comment: They are placed correctly..

Comment: have you included jquery js file ????

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Either I'm simply missing the problem, or your problem is not related to the code in your question. Have you definitely included jQuery? Do you have any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: I have not icluded this fie `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
`

Comment: However I have included JQuery.js from their official  website

Comment: Show your entire, unmodified HTML using http://jsbin.com/.

Comment: Check it out at http://jsbin.com/ocegod/1/edit

Comment: You must load jQuery before `jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js`. You're currently loading jQuery just before `</body>`.

Comment: hmm.. that seems to work.. Right now, one of my images is loading while others are not.. Anyways please post your comment as a solution so that I may accept it..

Comment: One image uses `images/abc.jpeg`, whereas the others use just `uvw.jpeg`.

Comment: No thats fine.. i have yet not organized the images.. It was the problem with extensions I guess !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you load jQuery before loading Nivo Slider:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```